# Shisha Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 106 quotations from *Tanach* in *mishnayos Kadashim*, according to Jason Kalman, "Building houses on the sand: the analysis of Scripture citation in the Mishnah", *Journal for Semitics*, ISSN 1013-8471, volume 13, number 2, 2004, pages 186–224. I haven't counted them, myself.

Answer (score 7):

Rambam (in his Sefer Hamitzvos, end of the section on positive commandments) enumerates 60 positive mitzvos that a typical man would perform over the course of his lifetime (barring unusual circumstances), of which 46 apply to women as well. So a married couple would, between them, perform 106 positive mitzvos.

(A stretch, I know...)

Answer (score 6):

106 is the denominator in an approximation of pi in a popular (for certain Jew-geeky values of "popular"), gematria-based [inference](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2010/03/happy-pi-day.html) from Sefer Melachim.

Comment: Believe it or not, this one came to my mind when I considered 106, not from random Jewgling of 106.

Comment: Or "106 is the gematria of the funny spelling for the word circumference, kava, in Kings."

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16892

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84337