# How the irrational number Pi can be derived from the Torah?

Tags: torah-study, pentateuch-chumash, mathematics

[Some traditions say](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=16258), based on a [Gemmorah in Taanis 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.9a.6?lang=bi) (also מדרש רבה נשא י' ו', זוהר פנחס רכ"א א, and more):

> "**ליכא מידי דלא רמיזא באורייתא**"
>
> "***There is nothing that is not alluded to in the Torah***"

That is, everything can be derived from the written Torah (the Pentateuch of 304,805 letters, and Gr"a adds from Parashat Bereshis alone etc). Many tried (and succeeded) to find certain **integers**, such as numbers and dates.

In what way can [**the irrational and infinite number Pi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) be derived from the written Torah?

*(to clarify, the question is not about approximation of Pi, it is about the possibility to derive an irrational number from  a list of letters*)

Comment: Just because it can be done in principle doesn't mean anyone knows how to do it in practice.

Comment: Are you accepting answers from Nach? In that case it’s trivial - the Gemara already discusses it.

Comment: @DonielF What Nach do you mean?

Comment: Do you only want answers that *correctly* derive Pi?

Comment: @Heshy Ditto; like finding a cure for cancer in the written Torah.

Comment: @AlBerko Melachim Aleph 7:23 says that the circumference of the Yam Shel Shlomo was 30 Amos, and the diameter was 10 Amos. The Gemara (Eruvin 14a) derives from here that halachically we can approximate π=3.

Comment: @DonielF I edited the Q, thank you. I meant an irrational number vs integers.

Comment: @AlBerko So you’re looking for an exact value for a number that goes on infinitely without repeating, from a text with a finite amount of numbers? Am I getting this right?

Comment: @DonielF Right, I'm looking for an idea how that can be done in theory.

Comment: @DonielF well, math textbooks define it in a finite number of characters.

Comment: I'd suggest first defining the natural numbers.  First you have to prove that they exist, which can probably be done using rules of drash on the Chanuka leining or the Musafin of Sukkos, where it says ביום הפלוני in a sequence.  Then you derive properties of addition from the totals in Bamidbar and Pinchas and multiplication from זאת חנוכה.  Rationals you can probably get from the numbers in Matos.  Negative numbers are harder, but maybe you can get subtraction from the population of Shimon (Bamidbar - Balak ~= Pinchas).  But I don't know how to make the jump to reals.

Comment: Maybe once you get to a certain point you can just say "We've proved [in a drash sense, not a mathematical sense] that these things follow the axioms of natural numbers, so now just open the most convenient analysis textbook and define the reals from them."  Then you can apply whatever proofs you like.

Comment: If not a dup of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16892/501 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84337/501 then those are answers to this.

Comment: Looking for an exact value for a number that goes on infinitely without repeating, from a text with a finite amount of numbers is a problem for https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Gemara Eruvin. Pi was not irrational in theire mind. The discovery of rational-irrational concept is posterior

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok any math textbook does exactly that!  It defines pi in a finite number of characters.

Comment: @kouty but the concept exists and is easy to define (well it took until Cantor to get a fully rigorous definition, but once you know about it it's easy to define).  The question isn't "did Chazal know about it", it's "can you derive it from Chumash".  Obviously Hashem knows about it, nobody is going to argue that it can't be there in principle, even if they argue on this understanding of that Gemara.

Comment: @Heshy I understand you. To try  find what we know now in torah is a strange, anyway this is not limud torah. To find what science will discover in future is also not torah but more interesting. nobody can make this

Comment: Just because PI is irrational (and even transcendental), doesn't mean you cannot describe it accurately in a finite number of syllables.   Just as an example, there are numerous infinite series that converge to Pi.  E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: Right there is an algorithm to calculate it

Comment: I don't understand. I posted twice an answer, and they disappeared.

Comment: The Vilna Gaon famously explains how a passuk in Melachim talking about circumference alludes to Pi (correct to five decimal points). https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/is-the-passage-describing-an-approximation-of-pi-or-is-it-one-of-the-miracles-of

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywesternwallnet/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/24191748/story-of-pi-1.pdf

Answer (score 17):

Pi can be derived from the Torah by rolling up a Torah scroll and measuring the end's diameter and circumference. The ratio between them will be pi.

Comment: No joke! See Bava Batra 14a

Comment: _it is about the possibility to derive an irrational number from a list of letters_ - I guessed he asked for it! :-D

Comment: Isnt a Torah scroll just a list of letters?

Comment: @DannySchoemann any math textbook derives pi from a list of letters!

Comment: Technically this would be a linear spiral, but you have my upvote.

Comment: Hah! One of the great *Ma'asei Hashem*! No matter who rolls a Torah, no matter how loosely or tightly it's rolled and no matter what the sixe of the Torah is, you get the same number by dividing the circumference by its diameter. Seems like a *nes* (miracle) to me! Who needs Euclid?

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4870/472).